# 'OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached' while exporting to json from pandas

Tags: json, pandas, to-json

I have a pandas pf with these types:

```
id                   14 non-null int64
class                14 non-null int64
action.start         6 non-null float64
action.end           6 non-null float64
action.text          6 non-null object
action.lemma         6 non-null object
```

When I run `df.to_json('output.json',orient='index')` (tried any orient option) it keeps crashing and with the error:

```
OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: can you show us your dataframe?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out I had some weird object type in the dataframe:

```
action.text <class 'spacy.tokens.span.Span'>
```

Turning this into text solved the issue